# How to use the camera calibrated parameters from app in Matlab to rectify the image sequence?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using the Matlab app "Stereo Camera Calibrator" (part of the computer vision toolbox). I need to rectify my images but I do not understand how to use the stereo parameters. I tried this:

```
[J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams);
```

How can I get the `stereoParams` which I need to input here?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Doesn't the app rectify the images?

Answer (score 1):

Before rectifying the stereo image pairs, you do need to perform the stereo camera calibration, and as you said you can use the Matlab Stereo Camera Calibrator application that gives you as output when you saved the session a `calibrationSession.mat` file in your Current Folder.

Then, after imported the two images (e.g., `I1 = imread('example.tif');`), you can rectify the stereo image pairs with the following command:

```
[J1,J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1,I2,calibrationSession.CameraParameters);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but still m not getting how to do it. my problem 
was that i need to rectify the live images for 3D reconstruction. i am using matlab camera stereo calibration app.but m not getting  how to use the app for rectification(especially stereoparameters from camera for rectifing) purpose.
i was bit trying to do it with code: [J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams); but not understanding how to use the stereoParams here since it is showing error of it(stereoparams) as undefined or how to process after the camera calibration?.

Comment: while saving the session of calibration  it is getting saved as microsoft access tablet shortcut but not as calibrationsession.mat

Comment: As far as I know, the Matlab Stereo Camera Calibrator doesn't rectify the image pairs on its own. It only offers the opportunity to see the image pairs rectified. You have to use the `rectifyStereoImages` function together with the outcome of the stereo camera calibration obtained from the Matlab Stereo Camera Calibrator application.

Comment: but how to call the 'stereoparams' for rectifyStereoImages to use in code:
 [J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams);

Comment: i am calibrating the two camera from Matlab app.

Comment: After achieved the calibration, in the Calibration tab of the application you can save the session. This will give you a MAT-file (that as default is called calibrationSession) containing the stereoParameters that you can access as structure (`calibrationSession.CameraParameters`) and put in the `rectifyStereoImages` function.

Comment: have save the calibration part in my folder of main program. i got this as microsoft access table shortcut type than i used rectification code: [J1, j2] =   rectifyStereoImages(IMa3,IMb3,calibrationSession.CameraParameters); Bro it shows error of : Undefined variable "calibrationSession" or function "calibrationSession.CameraParameters".

Comment: Did you load the MAT-file in the Workspace : `load('calibrationSession.mat')`?

Comment: Yes, i did that but still shows the same error.
Ii have also saved the matlab script of calibration part. Is it any helpful in rectification? m using Matlab R2015a.

Comment: I have one file of "stereoParams" in workspace which contains the data of calibrated camera.

Comment: when rectification is done it is showing two images in same frame. how to obtain the single image and  i am not getting the line in the  rectified frame.

Comment: If you are happy with my responses and comments, please vote me up!